# Angular js directive and repeater issue

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have this piece of code here

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
.directive('loadObject', function (repository, $rootScope) {
    return {
        scope: {
            loadObject: '@'
        },
        controller: ['$scope', '$http', '$attrs', function ($scope, $http, $attrs) {
            $attrs.$observe('loadObject', function (value) {
                var ob = $.parseJSON(value);
                if (ob.type) {
                    repository.get(ob.path + '/' + ob.type).success(function (itemList)    { 
                        $scope[ob.object + '-' + ob.type] = itemList;
                    });
                }
            });
        }]
    };
```

and this html

```
<div load-object='{"path":"contentFormService/byType","object":"contentForm","type":"Page"}' ng-controller="dControl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in contentForm-Page">
        {{item.Id}}-{{item.Name}}-{{item.User.Username}}
    </div>
</div>
```

everything works well the data is in the $scope but i cant see it in repeater

Edit:

as requested here is the Plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/z33KKM6V0pjS6wGRHAeO

Comment: Can you post what you have in a plunker or jsfiddle. http://plnkr.co/ or http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/z33KKM6V0pjS6wGRHAeO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with the code.

### **The syntax**

`contentForm-Page` is not a valid JS identifier and I suspect that Angular will try to parse it as `a - b` with `-` being treated as the subtraction operator. Then [JS magic might kick in](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat) and [give you strange results](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qftn6Nimybd2b8IAaDBu?p=preview). Try creating a *valid* JS variable name for use in the `ng-repeat` expression (omit the `-` in the name) or move the `contentForm-Page` to an explicit Object:

**Template**

```html
<div ng-repeat="item in pageData['contentForm-Page']">
```

**Controller**

```js
            var ob = $.parseJSON(value);
            $scope.pageData = {};
            if (ob.type) {
                repository.get(ob.path + '/' + ob.type).success(function (itemList)    { 
                    $scope.pageData[ob.object + '-' + ob.type] = itemList;
                });
            }
```

### **The semantics**

Now you are running into an issue with `scope` inheritance. You are *isolating* your scope at the `directive` level *and* you are *transcluding* HTML inside the directive. That is dicey ground: the `scope` in the directive's controller and link function will be available only to the `template` of the `directive` (which is not provided).

The `scope` available to the HTML inside is a *sibling* scope which does not contain the definitions made in the `controller` or the `link` function.

To fix this second problem, the simplest solution is to set `scope: true` instead of isolating it by providing `{ loadObject : '@' }`. The other solution would be to move the HTML to a `template`.

### **Working example**

Here is a working example with the `scope.$id` in the console and the HTML: http://plnkr.co/edit/i84Ix9V5F8rpDZlpTBDf?p=preview

Comment: @user2873685 In this case, I could work out what the problems were but it is usually better to say explicitly what you tried and what didn't work. Also, the plunker you provided had some errors which you could have noticed on the console. The issue was fun to track though. Have updated the answer with the second problem + solution. :)

Comment: this solution is basically better for my needs. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
.directive('loadObject', function (repository, $rootScope) {
    return {
        scope: {
            loadObject: '@'
        },
        template:'<div ng-repeat="item in contentFormPage">{{item.Id}}-{{item.Name}}-{{item.User.Username}}</div>',
        controller: ['$scope', '$http', '$attrs', function ($scope, $http, $attrs) {
            $attrs.$observe('loadObject', function (value) {
                var ob = $.parseJSON(value);
                if (ob.type) {
                    repository.get(ob.path + '/' + ob.type).success(function (itemList)    { 
                        $scope[ob.object + '-' + ob.type] = itemList;
                    });
                }
            });
        }]
    };

<div load-object='{"path":"contentFormService/byType","object":"contentForm","type":"Page"}' ng-controller="dControl">
</div>
```

i did this and it worked. It was an issue with isolated scope after all

Comment: This solution is for isolated scope i have accepted @musically_ut's answer because i needed my template on my html. On this example i would have to implement dynamic function returning template string to satisfy my needs

Comment: You can keep the template in a separate HTML file and use `templateUrl` key to point to it instead of `template`.